# Garbage Collection and Apache Commons Tuple Pair

Tags: java, hashmap, garbage-collection

I heard that there are some Java objects/classes like ConcurrentHashmap won't get garbage collected unless you explicitly clear them. But how about

> org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair

or its sibling classes like

> Triple

By the way is there a list of Java Built-in Classes that doesn't get garbage collected?

Thanks.

References:

- https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html
- https://dzone.com/articles/letting-garbage-collector-do-c

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think `ConcurrentHashMap` (which you misspelled) will not get GCed? All objects and classes in the JVM will be GCed if they have no (strong) references to them and the JVM wants the memory badly enough. So no, there's no such list of classes that don't get GCed because there are no such classes.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @Lew. Well me too, I never expected things like that to happen in my whole Java experience. But if you see the last link I have provided in my question. He explained it. I even made a simple code that demonstrates that one (which I took somewhere else too). If you want I can give you the code.

Comment: Demonstrates what, exactly? That "last link" makes no claims about classes that cannot be GCed.